# input type="time" apagar o value quando o checkbox for desmarcado

Tags: php, javascript, html, input

Bom tarde a todos. Eu tenho o seguinte código em HTML

```
<in﻿put type="checkbox" id="checkmarcacao1" name="checkm﻿arcacao1" value="checkmarcacao1">
<input type="time" id="hora101" name="hora101" disabled="disabled">
```

E tenho também o seguinte código em Javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(''input[name=checkmarcacao1]'').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is('':checked'')) {
        $(''input[name=hora101]'').removeAttr(''disabled'');
        } else {
        $(''input[name=hora101]'').attr(''disabled'',true);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Esse meu código em Javascript faz o seguinte: Quando meu Checkbox está marcado, ele habilita o input time. Se eu desmarcar o checkbox, o input time é desabilitado.

Acontece que se eu marcar o checkbox, escrever no input time, por exemplo: 12:34, depois desmarcar o checkbox o input time fica desabilitado porém o valor 12:34 ainda fica escrito nele.

Eu gostaria de saber como apagar o valor do input time quando o checkbox estiver desmarcado. ﻿

Quem quiser testar o código segue o link: https://jsfiddle.net/o8f3zvqu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, você pode limpar o valor do input com `.val()` toda vez que marcar o checkbox, que resolve o problema

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=checkmarcacao1]').change(function() {
    
    $('input[name=hora101]').val('') // aqui ele limpa o valor do input
    
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('input[name=hora101]').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
        $('input[name=hora101]').attr('disabled',true);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkmarcacao1" name="checkmarcacao1" value="checkmarcacao1">
<input type="time" id="hora101" name="hora101" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Obrigado andre_luiss. Resolveu o meu problema.